# ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130 ORA-29270: too many open HTTP requests

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

Hi I have the below procedure which calls a URL and posts JSON data before inserting or updating the table, it was working earlier.

```
create or replace FUNCTION post_vacant_list 
(p_id IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN clob
IS
    XML CLOB;
    v_data_post CLOB;
    resp utl_http.resp;
    req  utl_http.req;
    v_txt CLOB;
    url varchar2(200);
BEGIN
    url := '10.54.8.210:9200/temp/20';(http)
    xml := JSON_UTIL_PKG.REF_CURSOR_TO_JSON(get_employees(p_id));
    req  := UTL_HTTP.begin_request (url,'POST','HTTP/1.1');
    utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', length(xml));
    v_data_post :=xml;
    utl_http.write_text(req, v_data_post);
    resp := UTL_HTTP.get_response(req);
    utl_http.read_text(resp,v_txt);
    utl_http.end_response(resp);
    UTL_HTTP.end_request (req);
    dbms_output.put_line('v_txt'|| v_txt);

 exception

 WHEN UTL_HTTP.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS THEN
  UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(resp); 
    when others then
   UTL_TCP.Close_All_Connections; 
  RETURN sqlerrm;

    end;
```

However, now that I get the below error while trying to check for a different set of data (i.e., calling it from a package as above )

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
ORA-29270: too many open HTTP requests
```

Can you please help me with the above issue? How do I end the http connection ?

I have tried to add `End_response` and `End_request` to my procedure but looks like the issue is still persistent.

Comment: A more informative and concise title would improve this post.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thank you for editing my post, I am quite new to stackoverflow..my requirement is I need to fire a trigger before update/insert/delete action is performed on a table for which I have the below code :`create or replace TRIGGER POST_JSON_DATA_TRIG
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON emp_data
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
V_RET CLOB;
BEGIN
IF (:NEW.deptno<> :OLD.deptno) 
THEN
V_RET:= post_json_data_fnc(:NEW.deptno);
END IF;
END;

Comment: I have the below code available and I am able to convert the records to JSOn format ..but the requirement is I need to fire a trigger before inserting or updating the table and post the same on the local http url can you please help me achieve this?